# Oracle 11g SQL Create Table IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Trying write in Oracle 11g the equivalent to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblName
```

How do you do this in 11g? Would prefer to not use execute immediate or pl/sql.

Comment: @Mureinik I said do it without execute immediate. The answers in the question you linked all use execute immediate. Did you read the question before you marked duplicate?

Comment: the answer is simply: there is no way to do that without `execute immediate`